# RSS on a different thread doesnt work but works fine when on the main thread

Tags: iphone, nsthread

I'm trying to get an rss parser on a different thread in my iphone app, but when I do this I only get the spinning indicator (i.e., nothing).  But if I comment out the call [NSThread....] in viewDidAppear, and uncomment the line [self loadData], everything works (but then its not on a different thread).  Am I missing something?  Thanks for any insight you can provide here!!

Here is the code.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

              //[self loadData];

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}



- (void)loadData {

         NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if (items == nil) {
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];

        Parser *rssParser = [[Parser alloc] init];
        [rssParser parseRssFeed:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/xml" withDelegate:self];

        [rssParser release];

    } else {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
        [pool release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All UI changes should be made on the main thread:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if (items == nil)
    {
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)loadData {

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        Parser *rssParser = [[Parser alloc] init];
        [rssParser parseRssFeed:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/xml" withDelegate:self];
        [rssParser release];

        [pool release];
}
```

Check if `items` is null, if it is, start animating the indicator and *then* start the new thread.

Comment: Thanks..That makes sense, but I just tried it but it still results only in the spinning indicator. Again, if I comment out the NSThread line, and put in [self loadData] at that point, it works, which leads me to think something with NSThread call isn't correct or something...you think?

Comment: According to this:http://www.iphoneexamples.com/, you are using threading correctly. Have you tried `performSelectorInBackground:`?

Comment: Yes, well that works, and now I wonder why one works and the other doesn't..seems strange

Comment: Can you try `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Yeah..just tried that, but it doesn't work and even the spinning indicator doesn't show..very perplexing

Comment: This is strange. Could you try `performSelectorOnMainThread:`? This should work no matter what.

Comment: Yes, if I use performSelectorOnMainThread it works, but once I change it to performSelectorinBackground it doesn't.  Since the detachNewThreadSelector is also putting it on a different thread - and that doesn't work, it seems the problem is getting a thread different from the main thread.  Anyway, thanks for helping me on this one.